# jQuery - Can't append a dropdown inside db.transaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, select, transactions

I'm trying to set the options of a dropdown select dinamically with the results of a query using SQLite,

```
function getCustomers(){
        var query = "SELECT nomcli, codcli FROM cliente ORDER BY nomcli LIMIT 0, 20";
        $("#select").append("<option>IT WORKS</option>");
        db.transaction(function (tx){

        $("#select").append("<option>IT DOESNT!</option>");    

            tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, results){

                //DO SOMETHING HERE
            }, callBack);
        }, callBack);
    }
```

For some reason, once I'm inside the db.transaction, the append doesn't work. It doesnt throw any errors or exeptions in the console or anything, I'm very lost and having the hardest time trying to figure out why if I do the append OUTSIDE the transaction it works, and not inside.

Any help?

Comment: Where does the db.transaction function comes from? I mean, what's and where's the server side operation that fetches the results?

Comment: @aldux That's WebSQL. SQLite is an embedded database; there is no server.